# Does prototype really matter in JavaScript if the class will never be subclassed?

Tags: javascript

So, in answering another question on this site, I wrote a class for someone to create a BitArray instance in JavaScript.  The code I posted looked like this:

```
var foo = function(param1) {
    this._member = param1;
    this.getMember = function() { return this._member; };
    this.setMember = function(val) { this._member = val; };
    this.alertMember = function() { alert(this._member); };
    foo.STATIC_CONSTANT = "some value";
}
```

One of the comments I received was a rather stern "You should absolutely add the methods to foo.prototype instead of this".  If I take that criticism and apply it to the above, it turns the code into:

```
var foo = function(param1) {
    this._member = param1;
}
foo.prototype.getMember = function(){ return this._member; };
foo.prototype.setMember = function(val) { this._member = val; };
foo.prototype.alertMember = function() { alert(this._member); };
foo.STATIC_CONSTANT = "some value";
```

My question is, what's the difference here between the two approaches assuming foo will never be subclassed?

To be clear, I'm not advocating writing sloppy code - I credit the commentor with catching me being sloppy - but as I was conceeding to his correctness, it really did make me think - why should I prototype if I'm creating an effectively sealed class?

Is there some performance or functional consequence I'm missing here?  Or when a class won't be subclassed is using the prototype irrelevent?

Comment: Just for clarification: I did not say "methods should never be outside of the prototype" and this is absolutely not the case. There are plenty of valid use cases where you would want to have methods on your object instance instead of on the prototype of your objects. *This* is not one of them.

Comment: @Daniel Baulig - libel corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various reasons. Firstly though I guess speaking of classes in JavaScript is misleading. There are no classes in JavaScript, but only prototypes.

Let us analyze what actually happens in your first approach and what happens in the second approach. When  the code of the first approach is run it defines a function, which, when it is called as a constructor, will create a bunch of other functions and assign them to members of the newly created object. You should be aware that this is done every time you call the function. So if you call the function once, you will have one object with a total of 4 functions. If you call the function twice, you will have two objects with a total of 8 functions, and so on. Each time, you create a new object using this constructor you will create a complete set of functions for it. Each of those function will require memory. Also, modern JIT compilers trying to spot hotspots in your code might fail to identify those functions as hot spots, since instead of having one function that is called multiple times you have several functions where each is only called once. Additionally even if the JIT is able to spot those functions as hotspots, it will have to compile each of those functions separately which will require additional work.

That being said I believe the assumption "foo will never be subclassed" shouldn't be valid. You cannot assume that others won't want to inherit from your object or would like to augment the prototype of your object. This is currently not possible. Imagine I would like to change foo.STATIC_CONSTANT. I couldn't, because each time I construct a new foo, it will override my changed foo.STATIC_CONSTANT again. Same is true for any other augmentation I might like to do.

All these problems do not arise in the second, **correct object oriented javascript** pattern.

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer.  With respect to the subclassing, in the scope of this quesiton, I'm asking, with that assumption being valid, what are the consequences of ignoring prototype?  You answer that quite adequately though with respect to the per instance performance hit and optmization misses.

Comment: +1, nice explanation of what's going on in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference.

In the first example, every single time you create a new instance of the class, its methods are redefined. This makes it very much less efficient in terms of speed and memory.

To illustrate:

```
function C1 () {
    this.foo = function () { };
}

function C2 () {}
C2.prototype.foo = function () {};

c1a = new C1();
c1b = new C1();

c2a = new C2();
c2b = new C2();

c1a.foo === c1b.foo;  // false
c2a.foo === c2b.foo;  // true
```

Comment: Actually, they are not *redefined* (and it is not the class, but that's another question). The methods are defined from scratch.

Comment: well yeah, but the terminology does get confusing with Javascript OOP.

Comment: Okay, we may leave classes out, but the methods _are not redefined_. They are _not defined at all_ on `this` object when the constructor is executing, and if they were defined on the prototype, they would be accessible with it.

Comment: @whitequark: I'm not sure I'm following you here. Yeah, they're not *redefined*, you just get `n` different but equivalent functions, one for each time you instantiate a new object from the "class". In the "bad" example, they are being added to each individual instance of the class separately. In the "good" way, the functions are created once and added to the prototype. Because they exist on the prototype of the newly created object, they are accessible like you would expect. Also, inside the constructor they are still accessible, but only after they are defined for that instance.

Comment: Ah well. Probably what we're discussing here is not a JavaScript language issue, but a (my) English language issue. Nevermind.

Comment: @nickf - nice call on the equality check - I went with Daniel's answer for his thorough response on performance but I like the code based answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are creating three functions from scratch for each instance of the array. This has some memory cost; it can be discussed whether this cost is big or not, but if you'll try to create thousands of instances of this array, you will notice the difference.

The object creation will be a little slower, too, but not much on recent optimized runtimes (like V8).