# Minimizing canvas "bitmap" data size

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, canvas, base64

**Context:** multi-user app (node.js) - 1 painter, n clients

**Canvas size:** 650x400 px (= 260,000 px)

For the canvas to be updated frequently (I'm thinking about 10 times a second), I need to keep the data size as small as possible, especially when thinking about upload rates.

The `toDataURL()` method returning a base64 string is fine but it contains masses of data I don't even need (23 bit per pixel). Its length is 8,088 (without the preceding MIME information), and assuming the JavaScript strings have 8-bit encoding that would be 8.1 kilobytes of data, 10 times per second.

My next try was using JS objects for the different context actions like `moveTo(x, y)` or `lineTo(x, y)`, sending them to the server and have the clients receive the data in delta updates (via timestamps). However, this turned out to be even less efficient than the base64 string.

```
{ 
    "timestamp": 0, 
    "what": { 
       "name": LINE_TO, 
       "args": {"x": x, "y": y}  
    } 
}
```

It doesn't work fluently nor precisely because there are nearly 300 `lineTo` commands already when you swipe your brush shortly. Sometimes there's a part of the movement missing (making a line straight instead of rounded), sometimes the events aren't even recognized by the script client-side because it seems to be "overwhelmed" by the mass of events triggered already.

So I have to end up using the base64 string with its 8.1 KB. I don't want to worry about this much - but even if done asynchronously with delta updates, there will be major lags on a real server, let alone the occasional bandwidth overrun.

The only colors I am using are #000 and #FFF, so I was thinking about a *1-bit data structure* with delta updates only. This would basically suffice and I wouldn't mind any "color" precision losses (it is *black* after all).

With most of the canvas being white, you could think of additional Huffman run-length encoding to reduce size even further, too. Like a canvas with a size of 50x2 px and a single black pixel at (26, 2) would return the following string: `75W1B74W` (50 + 25 white pixels, then 1 black pixel, then 24 more white pixels)

It would even help if the canvas consisted of a 1-bit string like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000
```

That would help a lot already.

My first question is: How to write an algorithm to get this data *efficiently*?

The second is: How could I *pass* the pure binary canvas data to the clients (via *node server*)? How do I even send a 1-bit data structure to the server? Would I have to convert my bits to a hexadecimal (or more) number and re-parse?

Would it be possible to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972717/how-do-i-create-bit-array-in-javascript) as a data structure?

Thanks in advance,

Harti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out, finally. I used an algorithm to get the image data within a specified area (i.e. the area currently drawn on), and then paste the image data to the same coordinates.

1. While drawing, I keep my application informed about how big the modified area is and where it starts (stored in `currentDrawingCoords`).
2. `pixels` is an ImageData Array obtained by calling `context.getImageData(left, top, width, height)` with the stored drawing coordinates.
3. `getDeltaUpdate` is called upon `onmouseup` *(yeah, that's the drawback of the area idea)*:

   ```
   getDeltaUpdate = function(pixels, currentDrawingCoords) {   
       var image = "" + 
           currentDrawingCoords.left + "," + // x
           currentDrawingCoords.top + "," + // y
           (currentDrawingCoords.right - currentDrawingCoords.left) + "," + // width
           (currentDrawingCoords.bottom - currentDrawingCoords.top) + "";  // height
       var blk = 0, wht = 0, d = "|";

       // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas
       for (var i=0, n=pixels.length; i < n; i += 4) {
               if(
                   pixels[i]   > 0 ||
                   pixels[i+1] > 0 ||
                   pixels[i+2] > 0 ||
                   pixels[i+3] > 0
               ) {
                   // pixel is black
                   if(wht > 0 || (i == 0 && wht == 0)) {
                       image = image + d + wht;        
                       wht = 0;
                       d = ",";
                   }
                   blk++;

                   //console.log("Pixel " + i + " is BLACK (" + blk + "-th in a row)");
               } else {
                   // pixel is white 
                   if(blk > 0) {
                       image = image + d + blk;        
                       blk = 0;
                       d = ",";
                   }
                   wht++;

                   //console.log("Pixel " + i + " is WHITE (" + blk + "-th in a row)");
               }
       }

       return image;   
   }
   ```
4. `image` is a string with a header part (`x,y,width,height|...`) and a data body part (`...|w,b,w,b,w,[...]`)
5. The result is a string with less characters than the base64 string has (as opposed to the 8k characters string, the delta updates have 1k-6k characters, depending on how many things have been drawn into the modification area)
6. That string is sent to the server, pushed to all the other clients and reverted to ImageData by using `getImageData`:

   ```
   getImageData = function(imagestring) {
       var data = imagestring.split("|");
       var header = data[0].split(",");
       var body = data[1].split(",");

       var where = {"x": header[0], "y": header[1]};
       var image = context.createImageData(header[2], header[3]); // create ImageData object (width, height)

       var currentpixel = 0,
       pos = 0,
       until = 0,
       alpha = 0,
       white = true;

       for(var i=0, n=body.length; i < n; i++) {
           var pixelamount = parseInt(body[i]); // amount of pixels with the same color in a row

           if(pixelamount > 0) {
               pos = (currentpixel * 4);
               until = pos + (pixelamount * 4); // exclude

               if(white) alpha = 0;
               else alpha = 255;

               while(pos < until) {
                   image.data[pos] = 0;
                   image.data[pos+1] = 0;
                   image.data[pos+2] = 0;
                   image.data[pos+3] = alpha;                  
                   pos += 4;
               }
               currentpixel += pixelamount;
               white = (white ? false : true);
           } else {
               white = false;  
           }
       }

       return {"image": image, "where": where};
   }
   ```
7. Call `context.putImageData(data.image, data.where.x, data.where.y);` to put the area on top of everything there is!

As previously mentioned, this may not be the perfect suit for every kind of monochrome canvas drawing application since the modification area is only submit `onmouseup`. However, I can live with this trade-off because it's far less stressful for the server than all the other methods presented in the question.

I hope I was able to help the people to follow this question.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to keep the data size as small as possible

Then don't send the entire data. Send only the changes, close to what you propose yourself.

Make the framework such that every user can only do "actions" such as "draw black strokeWidth 2 from X1,Y1 to X2,Y2".

I wouldn't bother with some pure binary thing. If there's only two colors then that's easy to send as the string "1,2,x,y,x2,y2", which the other people will parse precisely the same way the local client will, and it will get drawn the same way.

I wouldn't overthink this. Get it working with simple strings before you worry about any clever encoding. It's worth trying the simple thing first. Maybe the performance will be quite good without going through a lot of trouble!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought first too (I had it approx. the same way).

I used objects like the following:


`{
 "timestamp": 0,
 "what": {
  "name": LINE_TO,
  "args": {"x": x, "y": y} 
 }
}`


However, with a single brush line of approximately 60x40 px, you'd have more than 300 of such commands already.
But the idea with simple (shorter) strings instead of objects sounds pretty good as well.

The object thing didn't work very fluently for me (on localhost). The Base64 string does work fluently, but I'm afraid that might only be the case for a LAN node server.