# How to pass bitArray from javascript to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-web-api, breeze, bitarray

I want to pass bitArray from my javascript file to my method in webApi

I create bitArray as below in my javascript file

```
 var myBits = new BitArray(2);
 myBits.setAt(1,false);
 myBits.setAt(2,true);
```

Then i call method in webApi which is as below

```
 public int ConvertArray(BitArray a)
    {
        //some logic
    }
```

I use Breeze to pass data to webapi, so i try to pass data as below

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("ConvertArray")
                  .withParameters({ a: myBits });
        manager1.executeQuery(query);
```

But when i put breakpoint in my webapi method i get blank data. But when i put breakpoint in javascript while i am passing data is get 2 records or i should say 2 bitArrays.

Does someone know how to pass bitArray to webapi?

**Update 1**

Here is how my bitarray looks like in my code
[image: BitArray]

Comment: What is your "JavaScript `BitArray`"? Looks like custom object of some sort...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i am using custom object

Comment: How does your json look like?

Comment: This might be completely off the mark, but maybe you will have to pass it as bit string to the web server and then convert it to a `BitArray` once you receive the string there. Just throwing out an idea...

Comment: @DavidSherret how can i pass it as bit string

Comment: @Happy I've posted an answer explaining how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to store the BitArray as a bit string before sending it to the server then convert it to a C# BitArray once the string reaches the server side.

**Javascript**

```
BitArray.prototype.toString = function() {
    this.m_bits.join('');
};
```

Use this method to make an array like `[ 1, 0, 1, 0 ]` change to the string `1010`.

**C#**

```
BitArray a = new BitArray(bitString.Select(c => c == '1' ? true : false).ToArray());
```

Comment: I get undefined when i use prototype.toString

Comment: @Happy you need to define `toString` as a function of `BitArray` that returns the underlying number array as string of `1`s and `0`s. The above is an example and you would normally use it by doing something like `myBits.toString()`. Maybe you could post the code for `BitArray`?

Comment: I got this idea of bitarray from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972717/how-do-i-create-bit-array-in-javascript

Comment: It worked when i used myBits.toString. Many thanks. But can you explain me about code new BitArray(bitString.Select(c => c == '1' ? true : false).ToArray()); I didnt understood much

Comment: Pass in `myBits.toString()` to the server and change the `ConvertArray` function header to be `public int ConvertArray(string bitString)` to accept the string. Once you have that string you can plug in that c# code above to get a BitArray from the string. What that code does is loops over each character in the string and creates a new boolean array where `1` => `true` and `0` => `false`. It then passes this array to the BitArray constructor which creates a new BitArray based on the boolean array.

Answer (score 1):

Breeze sends the query parameters in the URL, so they need to be serialized to a string.  Your `BitArray` prototype needs to have a `toString()` method that serializes the bits in a way that your server can understand.

Comment: Can you tell how to do?