# Is there a Boolean Typed Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

If I do:

```
var arr=Uint8Array(1);
arr[0]="hi";
console.log(arr[0]);
```

The result is `0` instead of `"hi"`. That’s because that type of object (`Uint8Array`) only admits 8-bit unsigned integers as values for its items.

Is there some type of array-like object made to store *only* boolean (`true`/`false`) values?

How can I create an object of that type?

Note: Please, don’t use `watch`; it’s not cross-browser. I’m going to use it in any browser.

Comment: `var arr = [true, false, true];` doesn't work for you?

Comment: var arr=[true,false,true]; arr[0]="test"; console.log(arr);

Try that.

Comment: It returns `["test", false, true]`. What's the problem?

Comment: **"test"** is not a boolean value. The idea is to make an array able to store boolean values exclusively.

Comment: The problem here is, you are assigning a string value to an Unit8Array. You can use it for only integer values. A Unit8Array can be used to store values from 0 to 255 I guess

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6973312/123415?

Comment: Honestly, why down vote this question?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76619183/213871) I made it in TypeScript, but you can use the `Proxy` class in pure javascript to simulate a boolean typed array with an API surface that is similar to other typed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what i asked for, but it could be a good implementation:

```
Uint8Array.prototype.getBitSum=function() {
 var _t=0;
 [].forEach.call(this, function(v, i) { _t+=Math.pow(256,i)*v; });
 return _t;
}

Uint8Array.prototype.getBit=function(b) {
 var _t=this.getBitSum();
 return ((_t & Math.pow(2,b)) != false);
}

Uint8Array.prototype.setBit=function(b, v) {
 var _v=v;
 if (isNaN(_v)) return false;
 var _B=Math.floor(b/8), _B_b=(b%8);
 if (_v) this[_B]|=Math.pow(2,_B_b);
 else this[_B]&=(255-Math.pow(2,_B_b));
 return true;
}
```

My limited knowledge about some terms made of this a hard work for me.
If you find some bug... add comment, please.

The reason of this is to minimize memory reservation. So I think it does right.

Comment: You could look up the << and >> operators.

Comment: You are practically doing bit packing which is an ideal way of creating a boolean typed array in JS. The only thing you may change is the `Math` object methods to their bitwise equivalents which are expected to result faster. Like dividing by `Math.floor(b/8)` is like `b >> 3` whereas modulo `b%8` would be just `b&7` etc... Check [this nice article](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1946)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have boolean-only arrays natively in JavaScript. Especially with legacy browsers support. Check the type of a value before inserting it into your array. If it's not a boolean, i.e. `typeof x === 'boolean'` then don't insert it.

Answer (score 0):

The only types supported for JavaScript typed arrays are the following:

- Int8Array
- Uint8Array
- Uint8ClampedArray
- Int16Array
- Uint16Array
- Int32Array
- Uint32Array
- Float32Array
- Float64Array

For anything else, you'd have to use standard JavaScript arrays like this:

```
var a = [true];
a[0] = false;
console.log(a); // false
```

Note that JavaScript being a dynamically typed language will let the developer also put values of other types into the array (such as `"hi"`). You can enforce types using functions that modify the array for the user after double checking the type:

```
function set(index, value) {
    if (typeof value != 'boolean') {
        throw new Error('Expected a boolean');
    }
    a[index] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not.  Here's the MDN documentation on [typed arrays in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) and you can see there's only typed arrays for various sizes of integers and floats.

As for why there's no "boolean typed arrays"?  Well, I think the primary purpose of typed arrays in JS is for efficiently handling large amounts of data for APIs, and there's really not a ton of demand for APIs to take a large amount of boolean data.

In short, the primary purpose is performance, not type-safety.  The purpose of typed arrays isn't really to prevent the wrong type of data from being added to the array.

But, if you really want a "boolean array", you could write a wrapper around a UInt8Array that stores and reads booleans, using bitwise operations to store the booleans as individual bits.  (i.e. something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972717/how-do-i-create-bit-array-in-javascript/6973312#6973312), though backed by a typed array) But I'd question the value in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a bitset in JavaScript. There are libraries implementing bitsets in JavaScript, see for example :

https://github.com/lemire/FastBitSet.js