# Declare an array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm having trouble either declaring or using a boolean array in Typescript, not sure which is wrong. I get an `undefined` error. Am I supposed to use JavaScript syntax or declare a new Array object?

Which one of these is the correct way to create the array?

```
private columns = boolean[];
private columns = [];
private columns = new Array<boolean>();
```

How would I initialise all the values to be false?

How would I access the values, can I access them like, `columns[i] = true;`?

Comment: correct syntax is let array: boolean[]; and yes you can access it the way you are using

Answer (score 404, accepted):

Here are the different ways in which you can create an array of booleans in typescript:

```
let arr1: boolean[] = [];
let arr2: boolean[] = new Array();
let arr3: boolean[] = Array();

let arr4: Array<boolean> = [];
let arr5: Array<boolean> = new Array();
let arr6: Array<boolean> = Array();

let arr7 = [] as boolean[];
let arr8 = new Array() as Array<boolean>;
let arr9 = Array() as boolean[];

let arr10 = <boolean[]>[];
let arr11 = <Array<boolean>> new Array();
let arr12 = <boolean[]> Array();

let arr13 = new Array<boolean>();
let arr14 = Array<boolean>();
```

You can access them using the index:

```
console.log(arr[5]);
```

and you add elements using push:

```
arr.push(true);
```

When creating the array you can supply the initial values:

```
let arr1: boolean[] = [true, false];
let arr2: boolean[] = new Array(true, false);
```

Comment: Is there a good reason for having so many different ways of declaring an Array? arr5 and arr6 seem particularly jarring to me.

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès It's just the way javascript is. Check out this question regarding arr5 and arr6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/coffeescript-array-vs-new-array

Comment: @juanjinario not really. there are two problems with it. the first is that you don't assign a real value to the variable, and so `array.push(...)` will end up in a runtime error. also, sine you haven't included any type for the array you'll get `never[]`.

Answer (score 19):

this is how you can create an array of boolean in TS and initialize it with false:

```
var array: boolean[] = [false, false, false]
```

or another approach can be:

```
var array2: Array<boolean> =[false, false, false]
```

you can specify the type after the colon which in this case is boolean array

Answer (score 9):

**Specific type of array in typescript**

```
export class RegisterFormComponent 
{
     genders = new Array<GenderType>();   // Use any array supports different kind objects

     loadGenders()
     {
        this.genders.push({name: "Male",isoCode: 1});
        this.genders.push({name: "FeMale",isoCode: 2});
     }
}

type GenderType = { name: string, isoCode: number };    // Specified format
```

Answer (score 7):

Few ways of declaring a typed array in `TypeScript` are

```js
const booleans: Array<boolean> = new Array<boolean>();
// OR, JS like type and initialization
const booleans: boolean[] = [];

// or, if you have values to initialize 
const booleans: Array<boolean> = [true, false, true];
// get a vaue from that array normally
const valFalse = booleans[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr1: boolean[] = [];

console.log(arr1[1]);

arr1.push(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on a implementation of a typed boolean array using the `Proxy` class and`Uint8ClampedArray` as the backing storage for the booleans:

```
class BooleanArray
{
    #actualArray: Uint8ClampedArray;

    [index: number]: boolean;

    constructor(length? : number)
    {
        this.#actualArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(length ?? 0);
        return new Proxy(this, BooleanArray.indexedHandler);
    }

    get length(): number
    {
        return this.#actualArray.length;
    }

    private static indexedHandler: ProxyHandler<BooleanArray> =
    {
        get(target, prop)
        {
            switch (prop)
            {
                case 'length':
                    return target.length;
                default:
                    return target.#actualArray[Number(prop)] !== 0;
            }
        },
        set(target, index, value): boolean
        {
            target.#actualArray[Number(index)] = value ? 1 : 0;
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

I tested it with:

```
var test = new BooleanArray(4);

test[1] = true;
test[3] = true;

console.log(test[0]); // Output: false
console.log(test[1]); // Output: true
console.log(test[2]); // Output: false
console.log(test[3]); // Output: true
console.log(test.length); // Output: 4
//console.log(test['str']); // Doesn't compile
```

Feel free to suggest improvements/fixes.