# Creating an array type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I created an array type in typescript which looks like this

```
export type RamenApi = [
    {
        "Brand": string,
        "Variety": string,
        "Style": string,
        "Country": string,
        "Stars": number,
        "Top Ten": string
    }
]
```

Now, In one of the places, where I am sorting and filtering the array, I am getting the following error

```
Property '0' is missing in type '{ "Brand": string; "Variety": string; "Style": string; "Country": string; "Stars": number; "Top Ten": string; }[]' but required in type 'RamenApi'
```

Any idea on why I am getting the following error and how I can fix it?

```
  type Props = {
        searchData: RamenApi, 

    const [filteredSearch, setFilteredSearch] = useState<RamenApi | null>(null)


 const {searchData} = props
            const tempFilteredSearch = []
                for (let i=0; i<searchData.length; i++) {
                    const currentResponse = searchData[i]
                    const searchVariable = currentResponse["Variety"].toLowerCase() + currentResponse["Brand"].toLowerCase() + currentResponse["Country"]
                    if (searchVariable.indexOf(text) > - 1) {
                        tempFilteredSearch.push(currentResponse)
                    }
                }
                setFilteredSearch(tempFilteredSearch.slice(0,5))
```

This is where I am getting error `setFilteredSearch(tempFilteredSearch.slice(0,5))`. Also, the code is cut short. ignore missing brackets or any such mistakes

Comment: There is no possible way anyone can answer this question without seeing the code which that error message refers to. Please write a [mcve].

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51467301/7867822

Comment: The type you defined means "An array that contains one element and this element is an object with fields: "Brand" of type string, "Variety" ...". But than you are trying to set an array with multiple items to the state of your type

Comment: @Shlang Okay, So how I can create my type to have multiple items?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. If you just want to have an array of strings it is `string[]`, if you want to ensure only limited set of string values can be put to the array it is `("Brand" | "Variety" ...)[]`.

Comment: @anny123 The syntax for array types is `T[]` or `Array<T>`. `[T]` is a tuple with one element of type `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of a `type` or a type `interface` will be and most likely the same as the object in that array.

Create something like this

```
export type RamenApi = {
        Brand: string,
        Variety: string,
        Style: string,
        Country: string,
        Stars: number,
        TopTen: string
    }
```

Then

```
searchData: RamenApi[], 

const [filteredSearch, setFilteredSearch] = useState<RamenApi[] | null>(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there s a typo.
What is declared there - is a type that ALWAYS have a SINGLE item for specified structure.

I may assume the intent was to declare array that MAY have from 0 to N items of defined structure, then the syntax should be like this:

```
export type RamenApi = {
    "Brand": string,
    "Variety": string,
    "Style": string,
    "Country": string,
    "Stars": number,
    "Top Ten": string
}[]
```